# final LayoutParams size=new LayoutParams(200, 25) is not working when i apply this on my EditTexts

Tags: android, android-layout

when i pass "size" as argument in code line it show no work......
Here is my code

```
     final LayoutParams size=new LayoutParams(200, 25);//globally declared 

        private void Add() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TableLayout myTable = new TableLayout(AddParing.this);
            EditText[][] myEditTexts = new EditText[2][2];
            myTable.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            TableRow[] myRow = new TableRow[2];
            for (int a = 0; a < 1; a++) {
                myRow[a] = new TableRow(AddParing.this);
                myRow[a].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                for (int b = 0; b < 2; b++) {

                    myEditTexts[a][b] = new EditText(AddParing.this);
                    myEditTexts[a][b].setText("");
                    myEditTexts[a[b].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.input_bar);
                    myEditTexts[a][b].setLayoutParams(size);
                    //myEditTexts[a][b].setHeight(15);
                    myRow[a].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    myRow[a].addView(myEditTexts[a][b]);
                }
                myTable.addView(myRow[a]);
            }
            TableLayout lin = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
            lin.addView(myTable);
        }

    });
```

i want to apply the `setlayoutparams()`. so how can i apply so it works correctly?

Comment: Here i want to add two EditTexts dynamically......I want to re size my new coming EditTexts..

Comment: Please explain your question more clearly to get answer.

Comment: I want to re size newly coming EditTexts. myEditTexts[a][b].setHeight(15) apply on them but width can't works on it

Answer (score 0):

```
 final TableRow.LayoutParams size=new TableRow.LayoutParams(200, 25);
```

use this code it works.